# Python Class gives "None in the ouptut"

Tags: python, linux, class, constructor

I have the following code:

```
class StudentData:
    "Contains information of all students"
    studentNumber = 0;
    def __init__(self,name,age,marks):
        self.name = name;
        self.age = age;
        self.marks = marks;
        StudentData.studentNumber += 1;
    def displayStudentNumber(self):
        print 'Total Number of students = ',StudentData.studentNumber;
    def displayinfo(self):
        print 'Name of the Student: ',self.name;
        print 'Age of the Student: ', self.age;
        print 'Marks of the Student: ', self.marks;

student1 = StudentData('Ayesha',12,90)
student2 = StudentData('Sarah',13,89)
print "*Student number in case of student 1*\n",student1.displayStudentNumber();
print "Information of the Student",student1.displayinfo();
print "*Student number in case of student 2*\n",student2.displayStudentNumber();
print "Information of the Student",student2.displayinfo();
```

And the output is:

```
*Student number in case of student 1*

Total Number of students =  2

None

Information of the Student Name of the Student:  Ayesha

Age of the Student:  12

Marks of the Student:  90

None

*Student number in case of student 2*

Total Number of students =  2

None

Information of the Student Name of the Student:  Sarah

Age of the Student:  13

Marks of the Student:  89

None
```

I can't understand why do I get these "None" in my output. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your functions `displayStudentNumber()` and `displayinfo()` do not return anything.

Try changing them to:

```
def displayStudentNumber(self):
    return 'Total Number of students = ' + str(StudentData.studentNumber)

def displayinfo(self):
    print 'Name of the Student: ',self.name;
    print 'Age of the Student: ', self.age;
    print 'Marks of the Student: ', self.marks;
    return ''
```

As the function does not return anything, it defaults to `None`. That is why it is getting returned.

By the way, semi-colons are not needed in python.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan Lol, not a problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be **returning** those strings, not **printing** them. A function with no return value, returns `None`. Also *please* don't use semicolons in Python.

```
def displayStudentNumber(self):
      return 'Total Number of students = {0}'.format(StudentData.studentNumber)
def displayinfo(self):
      return '''\
Name of the Student: {0}
Age of the Student: {1}
Marks of the Student {2}'''.format(self.name, self.age, self.marks)
```

Comment: I've +1'd this as well. `format()` is a very good way to go with this.

Comment: But it is a little complex for me. I know right now I am very dumb in Python :)

Comment: @AyeshaHassan Don't worry, we were all beginners at python once :)

Answer (score 1):

You get `None` in your output because you are printing the return value of calling the method `displayStudentNumber`. By default this returns `None`.

You either want to print the *return value* of a method or you just want to print. Try something like this,

```
print "Student number in case of student 1"
student1.displayStudentNumber()
```

or

```
def displayStudentNumber(self):
    return 'Total Number of students = %d' % StudentData.studentNumber
```

and

```
print "Student number in case of student 1", student1.displayStudentNumber()
```